# How to resolve the errors after updating a version of the TestFairy plugin?

Tags: flutter, dart, testfairy

I receive a lot the errors when I try to build iOS build.
My current version of TestFairy is 2.0.0.
Flutter version 1.22.2.
Dart version 2.10.2.

```
Xcode's output:
↳
    ../../../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/testfairy-2.0.0/lib/testfairy.dart:201:23: Error: This requires the null safety language feature, which is experimental.
    You can enable the experiment using the '--enable-experiment=non-nullable' command line option.
      static Future<String?> getSessionUrl() async {
                          ^
    ../../../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/testfairy-2.0.0/lib/testfairy.dart:416:13: Error: This requires the null safety language feature, which is experimental.
    You can enable the experiment using the '--enable-experiment=non-nullable' command line option.
          String? errorMessage) async {
                ^
    ../../../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/testfairy-2.0.0/lib/testfairy.dart:442:14: Error: This requires the null safety language feature, which is experimental.
    You can enable the experiment using the '--enable-experiment=non-nullable' command line option.
          {String? defaultText,
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the maintainer.

The version 2.0.0 can only work in projects which migrated to Dart 2 as the development language. If you don't want to do that, you can stay in the latest Dart 1 release.

```
dependencies:
  testfairy: ^1.0.25 # Dart 1
  # testfairy: 2.0.0 # Dart 2
```

For people who [migrate](https://dart.dev/dart-2) to Dart 2, make sure your project root has an `analysis_options.yaml` that looks similar to [this](https://github.com/testfairy/testfairy-flutter/blob/master/analysis_options.yaml). The important part is the enabled experiment in the top declaration.

You also have to enable the same experiment in your run and test commands:

`flutter run --enable-experiment=non-nullable --no-sound-null-safety`

`flutter drive --enable-experiment=non-nullable --no-sound-null-safety -v --target=test_driver/app.dart`

Comment: Hi @diegoperini is this working in production? I mean null safety feature is not currently released, so we have to switch dart to the dev branch to use 2.0.0?

Comment: It works in production. Not all code base of Flutter SDK is Dart 2 yet but the compilation works if you are careful with the version declarations.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you followed the ReadMe documentation of the Plugin then, try the following.

```
flutter clean
rm -rf ios/Podfile ios/Podfile.lock pubspec.lock ios/Pods ios/Runner.xcworkspace
flutter packages pub upgrade
```